# How can I add some dynamic fields and use them to get some math results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm using spring MVC and I have a form with dynamic field.

I can create several rows inside my form and each row has 4 input, like you can see below.

When I insert a number inside the second and third input field I want to multiply them and write the result into the fourth field.

How can I do it? Maybe using jQuery?

This is my code:

```js
var riga = 0;

function aggiungiRiga() {

  riga++;
  var objTo = document.getElementById('rigaOfferta')
  var divtest = document.createElement("div");
  divtest.setAttribute("class", "removeclass" + riga);
  var rdiv = 'removeclass' + riga;
  divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descrizione_"' + riga + '" name="descrizione[]" value="" placeholder="Descrizione"></div></div><div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-md-offset-1"><div class="form-group"><input type="number" min="0" step="0.01" class="form-control" id="prezzo_"' + riga + '" name="prezzo[]" value="" placeholder="Prezzo €"/></div></div><div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 "><div class="form-group"><input type="number" min="0" step="0.5" class="form-control" id="ore_"' + riga + '" name="ore[]" value="" placeholder="Numero Ore"/></div></div><div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 "><div class="form-group"><div class="input-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="totale_"' + riga + '" name="Totale[]" value="" placeholder="0" readonly="readonly"/><div class="input-group-btn"> <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="rimuoviRiga(' + riga + ');"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button></div></div></div></div>';

  objTo.appendChild(divtest)
}

function rimuoviRiga(rid) {
  $('.removeclass' + rid).remove();
}
```

```html
<div id="rigaOfferta">
  <jsp:text/>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descrizione_0" name="descrizione[]" value="" placeholder="Descrizione" required="required" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" min="0" step="0.01" class="form-control" id="prezzo_0" name="prezzo[]" value="" placeholder="Prezzo €" required="required" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 ">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" min="0" step="0.5" class="form-control" id="ore_0" name="ore[]" value="" placeholder="Numero Ore" required="required" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 ">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="totale_0" name="Totale[]" value="0" placeholder="0" readonly="readonly" />
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="aggiungiRiga();"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: JavaScript has basic maths like `+,-,*,/` etc... You need to decide when you want the calculation to trigger and bind a method to that event to the relevant element(s). Have a look at [**addEventListener**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) or if you are using jQuery at [**jQuery on**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) Ones you made your mind up how to trigger it and have issues with your code post it here and we can look why it isn't working. If you need to know how to write to an input with JavaScript, SO has plenty of examples for that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are going to have multiple input fields I suggest you add a class to them, something like `input-listener` and then a data attribute like `data-row="n"` where `n` stands for the row number. Then you add an event listener using jQuery (since it's easier) like so:

```
$('.input-listener').on('change', function(){
    var row = $(this).data('row'); //this way you know which row you are working with
    //now that you have the row you can get all the inputs you want
    var prezzo = $('#prezzo_' + row).val() || 0;
    var ore = $('#ore_' + row).val() || 0;
    $('#totale_' + row).val(prezzo * ore);
});
```

As I didn't test the code I am not sure if it works 100% but it can be a place to start. If you find any errors in the code let me know and I'll try and correct them.

The only thing is that if you add a new row you will have to rebind this event handler, so you'll have to find a way around that. Maybe add it in your `aggiungiRiga()` function.

Edit: I removed the `e` and changed it to `this` then I added the `#` to the ID of the jQuery selectors as I previously forgot to.